# How to install luarocks packages without internet?

Tags: lua, torch, luajit, luarocks

I used torch distro repository on github and installed LuaJIT and luarocks.

I want to install luarocks packages , from source, that is downloading the packages(.zip files) and building them from source .

I tried doing it by downloading the packages from github and then running luarocks install modulename.rockspec . But here it again starts cloning from github.

Can anyone tell me the exact procedure to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [source rocks or binary rocks](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Types-of-rocks).

#### Using source rocks

A source rock is a package with `.src.rock` extension containing the sources. You create it packing a rockspec:

```
luarocks pack bla-1.0-1.rockspec     # uses the network
```

This produces bla-1.0-1.src.rock. Running `luarocks build bla-1.0-1.src.rock` does not use the network to build `bla`, but it will hit the network to fetch dependencies if needed. So you need to pack and install all dependencies beforehand.

#### Using binary rocks

A binary rock is a compiled package with `.PLATFORM.rock` extension containing the .lua or .so/.dll modules. You create it building a module and then packing the code you built:

```
luarocks build bla-1.0-1.rockspec     # uses the network
luarocks pack bla                     # doesn't use the network
```

This produces a binary rock, say `bla-1.0-1.linux-x86.rock`. Note however that to install this in another machine, the target machine needs to be fully ABI-compatible, that is, all installed libraries in the source and destination machine need to be compatible (e.g. same OS/distro version). For this reason, this is useful for deploying rocks to multiple machines in a farm, but not for distributing binary packages for end-users in general.

#### Grouping packed rocks into a local server

Once you pack all rocks you need (and their dependencies) using one of the methods above, you can put them all in a directory, then turn it into a "local server":

```
mkdir my_rocks
mv *.rock my_rocks     # suppose we have some packed .rock files here
cd my_rocks
luarocks-admin make-manifest my_rocks
```

This works with both source and binary rocks. You'll then be able to build rocks from there without fetching the network.

```
luarocks install bla --only-server=/home/YOURNAME/my_rocks
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks a lot for the reply !!

I want to know what  *.rocks file in mv *.rock my_rocks

Comment: These referred to the *.rock files you can produce with pack, as I mentioned in the previous sections. I clarified the answer

Comment: Hi Hisham, Thanks a lot for this answer. If I want to use a remote private server to have a luarocks private server, how can I set up that server?

Comment: @AhmadGhadiri that is possible, but I think that's a different question to the one posted here!