# Setup a private luarocks repository

Tags: lua, luarocks

For my setup, I need to a private repository for luarocks rocks that I can install them on my development environment without connecting to internet. What are the steps to setup a remote repository for luarocks. Can I use a sftp server? Did anybody have an experience like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging more on this subject, I was able to set up a private luarocks repository with the packages that I needed. Thanks to the answer here: [How to install luarocks packages without internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845265/how-to-install-luarocks-packages-without-internet?answertab=active#tab-top), I set up an HTML server and copied my files in a directory, and created the manifest file. After that, I was able to point my luarocks to use that server to install the rocks that I needed.

```
mkdir my_rocks
mv *.rock my_rocks     # suppose we have some packed .rock files here
cd my_rocks
luarocks-admin make-manifest my_rocks
```