# tarantoolctl installation cartridge-cli && vshard

Tags: tarantool

after installing tarantool, I need to install cartridge-cli and vshard

when the Internet is connected, I did it from under the tarantool user:

```
tarantoolctl rocks install cartridge-cli 
tarantoolctl rocks install vshard
```

but now my servers don't have internet connection. what ways are there to install yet?

tarantool 2.2 installed from packages

P`S my question is how to install cartridge-cli and vshard without having an internet connection

Comment: It might be helpful to reword to clarify. Are you asking how one might install
software on a server that is *not* connected to the internet?

Comment: yes, my question is how to install cartridge-cli and vshard without having an internet connection

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your question.

First of all, stop use `tarantoolctl rocks install cartridge-cli`. cartridge-cli currently is static binary is written in Go. So you can deliver ready to use binary file to your server. See the latest version - https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge-cli/releases and download binary package dependent on your platform.

Secondly, there is a question how to deliver and install rocks if you don't have an internet access. Consider an example:

```sh
# I cloned vshard repository
# (git clone https://github.com/tarantool/vshard/tree/master/vshard && cd vshard)
➜  vshard git:(master) ✗ tarantoolctl rocks pack vshard               
Packed: /Users/o.babin/Projects/vshard/vshard-scm-1.all.rock

# vshard rock is actually simple zip archive that you can
# deliver to your remote server (e.g. via scp or by hands)
# Next you need to install it

➜  sandbox tarantoolctl rocks install ../vshard/vshard-scm-1.all.rock

No existing manifest. Attempting to rebuild...
vshard scm-1 is now installed in /Users/o.babin/Projects/sandbox/.rocks (license: BSD)
```

You could read more details how to setup private luarocks repository here: [Setup a private luarocks repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955879/setup-a-private-luarocks-repository)

Comment: Oleg Babin, Thank you so much for all your help